# How do i print a very large image, or at least save a very large image in a reasonable way?

Tags: image, image-processing, printing

I'm not really sure how to tag this question so i guess add tags if you think they're applicable.

I have a *fairly large* matrix that I've been asked to plot and perhaps get printed out for a poster. It's dimension is 70K. i.e. I have an array that's 70,000 square, and I have to plot it mapping the values of each element to some colour. That's not the hard part, I can do this.

The question is, how do I save such an image in a sensible way?

I realise that this is very strongly dependant on specific properties of the image. And i think this image could be problematic in that respect. The reason it's apparently interesting, is because it's quite fractal in nature. A lot of the image is just white though, if this would be helpful...

And then also, if i do get it printed, then even at 2400dpi, it's going to be a meter square, with just 1 *pixel* per matrix element. Is it going to look any good at all? or will it just look like a horrendous mess? (a reason for asking is that i can't just go and get it printed and see, because it could be a waste of £50!)

Comment: perhaps you could get a sample page of it printed for a cost of £2 and see if it looks good?

Comment: For saving huge images in Java you can use this: http://code.google.com/p/pngj/

Comment: One pixel square: What's important for this to work is that you ask the people that will do the offset to turn off anti-aliasing when scaling your image, or you will end up with an interpolated version of the image (=gradient transitions between the different colored squares).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your data looks, but I can think of a few good ways to do it:

1. Run Length Encoding - line by line, you list how many black, how many white, black, white in alternating patterns.
2. Coordinate lists - if you have a very sparse population, you could simply list the coordinates that are filled in.
3. White-boxing - this is just like listing out the bits one at a time (which in your 70k by 70k would be about 4.9b bits) except it begins by listing large rectangular areas that are nothing but white. As the bits are listed out, it skips over any that are in the initial list of boxes. When they're read in, it knows to skip over what's in the boxes too. With 12 bytes here (3 per coordinate) a 20 by 20 box (400 bits) or bigger might be represented. That would be about 10% compression. If you could get a 200x200 box you're looking at 1% compression.

For RLE, let's say you use 16 bits as your sample size. So if one of your rows started out  like this: `1245 white, 2 black, 100 white, 1 black, 834 white` You could encode this (in hex) `04dd0002006400010342` (note that 004d is 1245 in hex, etc...). Now that uses 80 bits and represents 2182 bits, or roughly 3.6% compression rate.

But rather than roll your own... I recommend, if you can, just use... PNG!

I made a random file that was a 7k by 7k (or 1/100th your total area). It had a random distribution of 1 black for every 100 white. It came out 677k, or roughly 11.3% compression rate.

I bumped it up to 20k x 20k (about 1/12th your total area) and it had a random distribution of 100:1 again. Its size was 5.4Mb, or roughly 11.1% compression.

So if your black to white is 1:100, I bet you'll be able to represent your file in about 11% the required bits, or under 600Mb.

Answer (score 0):

The human eye starts losing the ability to see individual pixels at about 300 DPI, so it doesn't make sense to have an image with more resolution than that. Thus this becomes an exercise in how to reduce the image resolution. At 3 bytes per pixel, your original would take 14.7GB so most off-the-shelf solutions are unlikely to be practical.

I'll assume you can read the data sequentially so that there's no need to have it all in memory at the same time.

One simple reducing method would be to read 8 lines at a time, then average each 8x8 area to produce one output pixel. This produces a 8750 x 8750 image which is still large but within the realm of reason.

There are resizing methods that produce slightly better results than averaging that you could run against a sliding window of your original. Overlapping the windows would be best to produce a seamless result.